# How to know which packages have been installed?

Tags: package, customize

Currently  I am experimenting with Emacs and playing with many `el` files. Sometimes packages are installed from those `el` files or I install with a command `M-x package-install`. But this may cause trouble in the future if I want to replicate my emacs configuration in other computers. Is there a way to keep informed which packages installed in my system and save them in one file automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Packages installed with `package-install` are stored under `.emacs.d/elpa/` directory. You can remove a package by deleting its directory e.g. `evil-20170802.1333` ;)

**Check out `use-package` package.** It provides a very useful macro:

```
(use-package my-favourite-package
  :ensure t)
```

This piece of code placed in `init.el` will install that package if it's not installed already, so you can simply move your `init.el` to another machine and the package will be installed automatically during startup.

There are some preparatory steps required for this to work (i.e. ensuring that `use-package` itself is installed and present), so find and follow a tutorial on `use-package`.

Comment: This is very useful, but just to be clear, this is declarative (you say what packages to install), not inquisitive. You won't be able to use use-package to replicate all the installed packages on your current system unless you find out what they are and set them up in use-package.

Answer (score 6):

```
M-x package-list-packages
```

At the end of the list are installed packages (printed in red).

Answer (score 3):

The list of packages you have selected is automatically kept in the variable `package-selected-packages` (which is saved via Customize into your `~/.emacs`).

Answer (score 2):

To "replicate" your configuration on other computers ...

> package-selected-packages is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.

> ...

> You can use it to (re)install packages on other machines
> by running ‘package-install-selected-packages’.

Comment: Noting that (as hinted at by the quote marks, I think) you're probably *not* replicating your original packages.  Rather, this will installing the most recent versions of those same packages.

Comment: Not what I had in mind. But yeah, that's a fair point.